# Dynamic target for intersect method in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

**Background:**
I need help adjusting a code I wrote by copy-pasting earlier. The goal of the function is to add a new row in a specified format whenever a target cell is clicked.

This was achieved via this code [excerpt only]:

```
Private Sub worksheet_selectionchange(ByVal target As Range)
If Not Intersect(target, Range("G6")) Is Nothing Then
  Rows("7:7").Select
  Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
  Range("B7:F7").Select
  With Selection.Font
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .TintAndShade = 0
  End With
```

It also works fine so far. However now I want to add this functionality to the same tab again for another cell range. The problem I have now is, that since the relevant rows are stacked vertically, whenever I add a row via the original function, the ranges defined in the second routine now no longer work.

**My Question:**
Can I define ranges for the Intersect method dynamically? My idea would be something clunky like having the second method refer to a variable instead of a fixed cell (MyRange) which is changed automatically by the first routine (e.g. MyRange = MyRange + 1). How would I do that? Or are there any other ways to achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is on the right track - defining variables beforehand and not hardcoding values in your code is one of the building blocks of maintainable code. There are many ways to do this, including having Excel search for keywords, etc.

My suggestion for your case is that you look into the Name Manager within Excel, and define a new name which refers to all cells that you would like to be watched by your sub. If you do this, Excel will track those cells the same as it would if you were just typing formulas within cells. ie: if you put in cell C5: "=A5+B5", and you insert a new column to the left of column B, C5 will automatically now read "=A5+C5". In this way, your VBA code won't change, but the values within your defined Name will change.

Without knowing exactly how your sheet is setup, here's an example of how you could actually do this:

```
    Private Sub worksheet_selectionchange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim CurrentRow As Integer
    Dim FormattedArea As Range 'This will hold the area of your row which you want formatted
    Const LeftColumn = 2 'this holds the left-most column of the area you want formatted...
    Const RightColumn = 6 'these hardcoded numbers will need to be changed if you want to format a different number of columns; if you have a dynamic way of determining them that would be best

    Set MyRange = Range("Possible_Areas") 'This makes MyRange = your defined, Excel-tracked name; you will need to go to the name manager in Excel and create it, listing all target cells you want included within it
    CurrentRow = Target.Row 'This will be used to find where to insert the new row, based on the current selection        

    If Not Intersect(Target, MyRange) Is Nothing Then
        Target.EntireRow.Insert 'Notice that I have removed your "selection" command - you can search this site for reasons on why ".Select" is problematic
        Set FormattedArea = Range(Cells(CurrentRow, LeftColumn), Cells(CurrentRow, RightColumn))
        With FormattedArea.Font
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Regarding your comments on the 6th code row, how could I dynamically define the number of columns that will be formatted?

Comment: @Zeiram That depends on what those columns are - do they have consistent header names? Then use the Find command to search for those names. Are they always 1 and 5 columns to the right of what is now cell A1? Then mark cell A1 and work to the right. Will they always be the same except that you might want to insert columns in between and before those positions? Then name a range and make the column #'s equal to the column value of those names [just as we did for the other named range]. You haven't told me what those columns really represent, so I can't answer directly.

Comment: @Zeiram If you have a new question on top of what you have already asked, you should ask a new question on the site; it makes the answers more valuable for individual users who may be searching for specific problems close to yours.